# is there a built in command that returns which array element contains a specific string in javascript

Tags: json, node.js

my question is that is there a command which can return for me which object has a specfic data. For example , if I have the following json data , I want to know which entry has Serial Number of value 11 which should return to me the index of that entry which is 0 :

```
[
  {
    "Barcode": "123451",
    "serialNumber": "11"
  },
  {
    "Barcode": "1234512",
    "serialNumber": "12"
  },
  {
    "Barcode": "123451",
    "serialNumber": "13"
  }
]
```

so basically i'm looking for something similar to (includes) but instead of stating true or false , it states which object has it :

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
data.somthing("13") 
returns : index=2 or last object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) methods are for:

```
data.find(e => e.serialNumber === '13')
```

Comment: what does this return ? , I'm console.loging it and its stating undefined

Comment: The comparison was wrong since serialNumber is a string, should work now.

Comment: Thanks , Does exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is array you can use `find` method of `Array` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
var obj = data.find(function(obj){

    return obj.serialNumber === '13';

});
```

Comment: The find() method returns a value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing.

Comment: I get the following error :      return obj.serialNumber === 13;
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'serialNumber' of undefined

Comment: @nero there was a typo `function(obj)` was `function(object)` I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and check each value with [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
data.forEach(function(obj, index) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (value == "13") {
      console.log('found index ' + index);
    }
  }
});
```

If you performance concern, you have to use other data structure or data storage for quick searching.

Comment: Thanks , but I'm trying to avoid loops as much as possible for my application

Comment: Yes, it would be a problem if the array is huge. Searching in an array of objects is a bad idea. If you want performance, you have find a way to index the data in the array.